# How to dynamically add "#" for the div id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to add dynamic image tag to the dynamic div when we click on thumb images. Please find the code below and am not able to set the img tag to dynamic div using  html().

Div is under the asp.net control

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setImage(Divid) {

        $(Divid).html("<img style=\"height:150px;width:150px;\" src=" + "" + names + "" + ">"); 

    }
</script>
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer as to what you're after? Sorry, but I can't make much sense of this question.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Didn't really understand what you where asking.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        function getbigimage(divid) {


        
  $(divid).html("<img style=\"height:150px;width:150px;\" src=" + "" + names + "" + ">"); 
 
        }
    </script> Hope this helps

Comment: What? Other than the function name, the code in the comment looks exactly the same as the code in the question.

Comment: Why the `asp.net` tag? There is no ASP specific code here...

Comment: You don't look for my mistake. try to help me out with the problem.

Comment: <div id="<%# getimgid() %>" class="productImage"> <a href="<%#GetProductLinks() %>"> <img id="a1aa" height="150" width="150" src='/en/images/Products/<%#Eval("Imagename") %>'> </a> </div> For this I have to set the div id

Answer (score 2):

Use your function like below.

```
function setImage(Divid)
 { 
  $('#'+Divid).html("");
 }
```

Comment: I done this already but am getting null value while am testing to get the html content for that particular div

Comment: here is the code I tried alert($('#'+n).html())

Comment: When you are trying to call your function??

Answer (score 0):

While creating dynamic div give an id

like

```
var createDiv =('<div id="dynamicdiv"></div>');
```

then after append the image to it

```
var dynamicImageDiv =         $('#'+dynamicdiv).html("<img style=\"height:150px;width:150px;\" src=" + "" + names +"" + ">");
```

Make sure the dynamic div created before you are appending to it .

Comment: Ok thanks. I got another issue after implementing this. to fix I would like to know, How to set Div id for the older one div using jquery or js

Comment: Try to edit your post and show us for which div you need to set the id..

Comment: <div id="<%# getimgid() %>" class="productImage">
                                    <a href="<%#GetProductLinks() %>">
                                        <img id="a1aa" height="150" width="150" src='/en/images/Products/<%#Eval("Imagename") %>'>
                                    </a>
                                </div>    For this I have to set the div id

Comment: By default am getting the div id from somewhere and when clicking on some thumb images, I want to set the clicked thumb image to inside the above mentioned div using html(). So for this I need help to set the div id to the above div

Comment: you can set the thumb image by using the class productImage. No need of ID in this case.

Comment: Not exactly. I put across my complete code above and its inside item template. we have to set the unique id for each because, in the same page we do have many images so we cannot use static class name for this. If we use class name then It will replace with other images